# Как сделать layout, который можно скроллить в любом направлении?

Tags: java, android, xml

В моём приложении есть контейнер LinearLayout(vertical), в котором создается определенное количество LinearLayout(horizontal), в которые добавляются TextView.

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы полученное поле можно было скроллить в любом направлении, в случае если оно не влезет на весь экран. Пытался реализовать через два ScrollView: vertical, а в нём horizontal, но тогда нет возможности скроллить по диагонали или под углом 30 градусов например, та и сам скроллинг получается "с костылями".

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Писать свой  ViewGroup который будет измерять себя в зависимости от каких-то входных параметров. Просто так из коробки вы этого не сделаете. Может стоит поискать какие-то библиотеки