# Нужен скроллинг в любом направлении

Tags: java, android, xml

Необходимо создать View, которое позволит скроллинг в любом направлении и масштабирование.
Пока что использую ScrollView (vertical), в котором лежит ещё один ScrollView(horizontal), но в таком случае я не могу скроллить по диагонали например, к тому же такой скроллинг "на костылях".

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы думаете если задать второй раз тот же вопрос, то получите другой ответ? Вам ответили уже в прошлый раз. Из коробки - никак! Нужно писать свою View.

Comment: Данный вопрос уже был задан ранее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1166238/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-layout-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8

Comment: Sergei Buvaka, благодарю за ответ.
Задал вопрос второй раз, потому что в личном кабинете stackoverflow первый опрос пропал.